# What is a substitute for Miso Dressing?

Tags: substitutions

I got a recipe coming up for Thai Fish Cakes. The recipe calls for Miso Dressing to be put on top of the fish cakes. Problem is, I can't find Miso Dressing in the stores I shop at ( I live in Central AZ ), and getting it from Amazon is too expensive or too large for something I infrequently use.

Nothing really spicy, please. My roommate can't handle the spice.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's either a recipe request, too broad or opinion based. There are many substitutes and it's all according to taste. Miso dressing is very simple to make and not spicy, why not get the ingredients and whip some up?

Answer (score 1):

To replace miso, you can use soy sauce, tahini or fish sauce for that umami and savoury flavour.